# Problem accessing res/raw resources on phone... works fine in emulator

Tags: java, android, resources

I am trying to access resources in the `/res/raw` folder programmatically (specifically... mp3 files). In the emulator, the following template works for me.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.foo.bar/raw/name_of_resource");
MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
```

On an actual phone, the `MediaPlayer.create()` method returns null. What gives? Is there a better way of accessing resources programmatically?

P.S.

I am not using `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.name_of_resource)` for a reason. In my particular situation, is much much easier for me to generate the name of the resource than figure out the `id` of the resource. (i.e. I can figure out the `String` `name_of_resource` fairly easily, but deducing the actual `integer id` `R.raw.name_of_resource` would involve a a lot more work and a lot more `switch` statements.

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue?  I think the emulator gives you more access then an actual device.  How about using reflection?

Comment: I don't think it's a permission issue. If I give the program an arbitrary mp3 to play, it works fine. How do you recommend I use reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way of accessing resources programmatically?

Use the static `create()` method on `MediaPlayer`.

> In my particular situation, is much much easier for me to generate the name of the resource than figure out the id of the resource.

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to get your resource ID.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you suggested, I have tried the getResources().getIdentifier() to no avail (it still works on the emulator though). I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'use the static create() method on MediaPlayer'. The method I used in the original post is static. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Because the code works in the emulator, I have a feeling it is fine. Is there any other reason my phone would not be able to access the raw resources?

Comment: @dfetter88: Here is a sample project that plays audio stored as a raw resource: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Audio -- it works fine on hardware and in the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up reverting to an earlier version and doing some rewrites. It all works now, even though I still don't know where I originally went wrong.